# React Native build on Xcode - YogaKit Include of non-modular header inside framework module & could not build Objective - module 'YogaKit'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native, build, cocoapods

I'm trying to build my React Native app on Xcode but I'm getting the errors below in the screenshot, I tried every solution I found on the internet but nothing worked!

I think that this error appeared when I installed and configured Firebase but I'm not 100% sure.

Xcode version: 14.3.1
React Native version: 0.71.8

here is my Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

pod 'RNDateTimePicker', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/RNDateTimePicker.podspec'

pod 'Firebase/Core', :modular_headers => true
pod 'Firebase/Auth', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'projectName' do
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'projectNameTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    
  end
  
end
```

I tried to delete DerivedData, I allowed 'non-modular includes in Framework..' in Build settings. I also deleted pods, podfile.lock, I marked the files as "public" but nothing worked ...[Screenshot of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jICad.png)